# Long Running WCF Service

Tags: wcf

I want to build a service that creates a thread on startup. The WCF service then receives requests and puts work onto the queue to be processed by the background thread.

Ideally, I think this would be easiest if the WCF service is hosted by IIS, but it doesn't seem that you can create a long running background thread like this.

How can I accomplish this with WCF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a long-running background thread, consider hosting the WCF service in a Windows service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx